# TypeError: cannot concatenate a ninNDFrame object while trying to concat

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lV4uw.png)This is my code and I am trying to concatenate on `axis=0` or append but I get this error. All the columns are the same and even the datatypes are same.

Although when doing a `pd.read_csv()` I have to specify `encoding=ISO-8859-1`
Do you think that could be the reason for it?
Although the type is a dataframe

```
declinedataforclassification=declinedata[['amount_requested','Risk_Score','dti','State','emp_length','policy_code','app_month']]
loandataforclassification=loandata[['loan_amnt','Risk_Score','dti','addr_state','emp_length','policy_code','issue_month']]
loandataforclassification=loandataforclassification.rename(columns={'loan_amnt':'amount_requested','addr_state':'State','issue_month':'app_month'})
declinedataforclassification['status']=0
loandataforclassification['status']=1
loandataforclassification['amount_requested']=loandataforclassification['amount_requested'].astype(float)

resultdata = loandataforclassification.append('declinedataforclassification',ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Found the problem was doing a stupid mistake of putting the df name in quotes inside the append

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
resultdata = loandataforclassification.append(declinedataforclassification,ignore_index=True)
```

should work for you. You're trying to append a string to a data frame right now.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but if you recognise this as a "stupid mistake", don't answer it. We have a close reason called "typographical errors" based on which posts like this must be closed. If you recognise this as one of those, you should be voting to close, or encouraging closure (if you can't vote yet). Answering them to farm rep points isn't really the best approach.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, was just trying to answer the OP's question.